# Hive copy data from one partition to another

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table which is partitioned on date. I have data for date "2020-08-18". I want to copy(duplicate) the same data into another partition.

Is there a command like this to do it

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE date = "2020-08-18" INTO table_a WHERE date = "2020-08-10"
```

Answer (score 2):

the below query might be helpful to you,

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_a PARTITION (odate="2020-08-18") 
select empdate,empvalue from table_a where odate='2020-08-10';
```

Note: Don't include the partition column in the select statement.

```
create table if not exists table_a (empdate string, empvalue string) PARTITIONED BY 
(odate string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_a PARTITION (odate="2020-08-10") 
values ('101001','A'),('200101','B'),('100619','C'),('110707','D');

hive> select * from table_a;
OK
101001  A       2020-08-10
200101  B       2020-08-10
100619  C       2020-08-10
110707  D       2020-08-10

-- dont include the odate column in the select statement otherwise it will lead
-- to  Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different
-- '"2020-08-18"': Table insclause-0 has 2 columns, but query has 3 columns error.


INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_a PARTITION (odate="2020-08-18") 
select empdate,empvalue from table_a where odate='2020-08-10';

hive> select * from table_a;
OK
101001  A       2020-08-10
200101  B       2020-08-10
100619  C       2020-08-10
110707  D       2020-08-10
101001  A       2020-08-18
200101  B       2020-08-18
100619  C       2020-08-18
110707  D       2020-08-18
```